# Adding a custom logout success handler does not seem to work for Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm having a strange problem that maybe you can help me solve with Spring Security.

I have a configuration class like this:

```java
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @Configuration
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
            .apply(login())
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("https://www.google.com")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**")
                        .hasRole("API_USER");

      }
}
```

the apply is applying a custom security configurer that adds a logout handler and exception handling for access denied and allowing static assets to be passed through such as favicon.

When I debug, I see the `LogoutFilter` being created but I don't see my `logoutSuccessUrl` being set as the target URL for the `simpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler`.  I'm also making sure I'm doing a `POST` to `/logout` with the CSRF token. I know ordering matters so I was wondering if anyone could point out a glaring flaw.

Login method is basically this:

```java
@Override
public void init(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(myCustomAccessDeniedHandler)
        .and()
        .logout()
            .addLogoutHandler(myLogoutHandler)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/favicon.*", "/public/**")
                .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: did you implement LogoutSuccessHandler?

Comment: @Generic I did not, I didn't think I needed to with the logoutSuccessUrl.

Comment: @dur yep, being redirected to /login?logout instead of my defined url.